# Odoo 9: create calendar event via python code (server action)

Tags: python, calendar, odoo-9

In my Odoo 9.0 community version I've installed the Calendar app.

I would like to know if it is possible to create events via server action that executes python code. I haven't found any samples about it.

The only sample code found is about creation of Google Calendar event in python [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/python#step_3_set_up_the_sample) but I don't know if it is useful.